# Sending TFTP packets in C++

Tags: c++, udp, client, tftp

I am relatively new to C++, so please forgive my lack of knowledge. I need help regarding TFTP packets. Below is the code I am using to generate a WRQ (write request package) and DATA packet which will be sent to a designated server.

```
bool createWRQ(char * filename)  {
  /*  structure is the same as RRQ  */
  clear();
  addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_WRITE);
  addString(filename);
  addByte(0);
  addString(TFTP_DEFAULT_TRANSFER_MODE);
  addByte(0);
  return true;
}

bool createData(int block, char * mData, int data_size)  {
  /*      2 bytes    2 bytes       n bytes
  ----------------------------------------
   DATA  | 03    |   Block #  |    Data    |
  ---------------------------------------- */

  clear();                     // to clean the memory location
  addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_DATA);
  addWord(block);
  addMemory(mData, data_size);
  return true;
}
```

I will include the declarations and required functions.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WebComm.h"
#include "WebCommDlg.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "visa.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>

int      mCurPacketSize = 512;
char     mData[512]; 

#define VIBUF_LEN 255

#define TFTP_OPCODE_READ     1
#define TFTP_OPCODE_WRITE    2
#define TFTP_OPCODE_DATA     3
#define TFTP_OPCODE_ACK      4
#define TFTP_OPCODE_ERROR    5

#define cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE 1024
#define cTFTPPacket_DATA_SIZE 512
#define TFTP_DEFAULT_TRANSFER_MODE "octet" //"netascii", "octet", or "mail"

typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;    



bool addByte(BYTE b) {
  if(mCurPacketSize >= cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE)
    return false;
  mData[mCurPacketSize] = (unsigned char)b;
  mCurPacketSize++;
  return true;
}


bool addWord(WORD w)  {
    w = htons(w);
  if(!addByte(*(((BYTE*)&w)+1))) 
    return false;
  return !addByte(*((BYTE*)&w));
}

bool addString(char * str)  {
  int n = strlen(str);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    if(!addByte(str[i])) 
      return false;
  return true;
}



bool addMemory(char * buffer, int len)  {
  bool oStatus = false;

  if(mCurPacketSize + len >= cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE)   {
    AfxMessageBox("Packet max size exceeded");
    return false;
  } else {
    memcpy(mData + mCurPacketSize), buffer, len);
    mCurPacketSize += len;
    return true;
  }
}


void clear() {
  mCurPacketSize = 0;
  memset(mData, mCurPacketSize, cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE);
}
```

I am aware these function have been declared mostly as type bool, however I need to send a WRQ packet to the server and wait for an ACK response before sending a DATA packet.

Something along the lines of:

```
while(/* something */)
  if(!sendto(socket, WRQ, 512, NULL, (sockaddr*)&Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)))){
     if(!recvfrom(socket, ACK, /* ... */))
         sendto(socket, DATA_Packet, 512, NULL, (sockaddr*)&Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))));
```

My question is: how can I modify the `createWRQ()` and `createData()` functions so that I can return them as packets to use for transmission, since bool only returns true or false as 1 or 0.
I need to be able to send them using the winsock send and receive functions. Apologies for the silly question. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

your whole approach has a few issues...

1. When you create your packets relying on functions like

   ```
   bool addByte(BYTE b)
   ```

   they use global variables

   ```
   mCurPacketSize, mData
   ```

   that's not good. You could use instead something on these lines

   ```
   int addByte(char* Pkt, int PktIdx, BYTE b) 
   {
    if (PktIdx > cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE) 
     {
           return 0;
     }
   Pkt[PktIdx] = (unsigned char)b;
   PktIdx++;
   return PktIdx;
   }
   ```

then you know that Pkt is always the head of your packet and PktIdx is either the place for a new byte (or string) and "also" the size of the packet.

2. When you create packets that have a fixed length structure (or a fixed length header followed by a variable length payload area) it is a good idea to represent the fixed length area with a "packed" (pay attention to memory alignment) C/C++ structure and then populate the structure.